# Python Error: get_exchange_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, binance

Getting error "TypeError: get_exchange_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
reference: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#id5

```
from binance.client import Client
import config

client = Client(config.apiKey,config.apiSecurity)
print("logged in")

info = client.get_exchange_info('LINKUSDT')
print(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this method doesn't accept any input params, check the docs: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#id4

Maybe you want to use this one: `info = client.get_symbol_info('BNBBTC')`

Comment: Oh lol I was using 'exchange' instead of 'symbol', haha my bad xD

Answer (score 1):

```py
from binance.client import Client
import config

client = Client(config.BINANCE_API_KEY,config.BINANCE_SECRET_KEY)
print("logged in")

info = client.get_exchange_info()
print(info)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is over a year old and already has three answers, all of which provide an explanation in addition to code. Are you sure this answer wasn't already given? If so, please [edit] it and clearly explain how it is better than what's already here.

Answer (score 0):

form the source code we have

```
def get_exchange_info(self):
    """Return rate limits and list of symbols
```

that mean get_exchange_info doesn't take any input

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=get_exchange_info#binance.client.Client.get_exchange_info) `get_exchange_info` doesn't take parameters. You can see the method doc and example output there.